# socket programming in c++ or VC++.net

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, sockets

I am a new developer of C++ and i want to do socket programming in c++ or VC++.net.
If you have good and easy to learn tutorial for socket programming in c/c++ please share the link.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft themselves, you can use winsock and read their guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545(VS.85).aspx

You can also use `boost.asio` which uses the more cross-platform Boost library.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

I learned a lot at the beginning reading [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: +1.  Beej's guide looks significantly upgraded since I read it 8-9 years ago :) (at least, I think that was the site...)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials for you which I had referred to recently:
http://shoe.bocks.com/net/

for more u can even refer to a book by Richard Stevens on Networked Game Prigramming.

Comment: A few more links:
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Answer (score 0):

edit: oops -- this is if you're interested in Unix, if you only want Windows, ignore the rest of this answer.

Try Unix Network Programming. You'll learn A LOT, and I do mean A LOT. After you've done sockets in C and learned protocols form that book, you'll understand working with them in any language, in any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the Free Framework](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html) for an introduction to high-performance Windows socket code. I find this a bit easier to follow than the Boost.ASIO code, probably because it's single-platform.